# Problem obtaining STL file from Graphics

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing, stl-format

I want to 3d print this solid (Riemann sums):

```
f[x_, y_] := 3/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)
model = GraphicsRow[{With[{h = .5}, 
Graphics3D[{(Cuboid @@ # &) /@ 
   Flatten[Table[{{x, y, 0}, {x + h, y + h, f[x + h/2, y + h/2]}},
     {x, -2, 2 - h, h}, {y, -2, 2 - h, h}], 1]}, Axes -> True]]}]

Export["riemann.STL", %]
```

I get the error message "Export::type: Graphics cannot be exported to the STL format."

How can I change my code so that I can print this solid?

[image: riemann sum]

Comment: Remove the `GraphicsRow` and `List` wrappers. The Export examples in the `"STL"` documentation are not wrapped in GraphicsRow.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[model];
f[x_, y_] = 3/(x^2 + y^2 + 1);
model = With[{h = .5}, 
  RegionUnion[(Cuboid @@ # &) /@ 
     Flatten[Table[{{x, y, 0}, {x + h, y + h, 
         f[x + h/2, y + h/2]}}, {x, -2, 2 - h, h}, {y, -2, 2 - h, h}],
       1], Axes -> True]]
Export["riemann.stl", model]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW,I don't know how to use DiscretePlot3D to plot such region.`DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2, .5}, {y, -2, 2, .5}, ExtentSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1]` does not plot the same region.

Answer (score 4):

You can also avoid the region stuff (RegionUnion and Cuboid) by using DiscretizeGraphics. You can generate an appropriate graphic with ListPlot3D.

```
model =
  With[
    {h = .5},
    ListPlot3D[Table[f[x, y], {x, -2 + h, 2, h}, {y, -2 + h, 2, h}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Axis]]
```

My adjustments for making the Table might be wrong in the details, but hopefully you can see how this would work with ListPlot3D. Now,

```
printableModel = DiscretizeGraphics[model]
```

And finally,

```
Printout3D[printableModel, "riemann.stl"]
```

Although, in this particular case, it appears that you can skip the DiscretizeGraphics step. The following also seems to work:

```
Printout3D[model, "riemann.stl"]
```

Using Printout3D is also somewhat nicer that Export, because it'll do some model verification (although in my experience it can sometimes still produce a model that some slicers can't handle).

Answer (score 2):

This comes only as a supplement to solution suggested by [`cvgmt`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265634/problem-obtaining-stl-file-from-graphics/265639#265639) plus the comment underneath it.

---

- Using [`DiscretePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html)

---

We have:

```
Quit[]

$Version

"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

f[x_, y_] := 3/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)

With[{h = 0.5}, 
 DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2, h}, {y, -2, 2, h}, 
  ExtentSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]]
```

> [image: dplt3d]

---

### **Edit: the part of code which I missed as I copied and pasted here.**

---

```
model = DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ExtentSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]

Export["riemann.stl", model]
```

and then we [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) what we did

```
Import["riemann.stl"]
```

the output of which is

[image: import]

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work.

Comment: @epsilon glad I helped!